# Why am I not getting a connection error when my API request fails on dropped wifi?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am pulling data down from an API that has a limit of 250 records per call.  There are a total of 100,000 records I need to pull down doing it 250 a time.  I run my application leveraging the **get_stats** function below.  It works fine for awhile but when my wifi drops and I am in the middle of the get request the request will hang and I won't get an exception back causing the rest of the application to hang as well.

I have tested turning off my wifi when the function is NOT in the middle of the get request and it does return back the ConnectionError exception.

How do I go about handling the situation where my app is in the middle of the get request and my wifi drops? I am thinking I need to do a timeout to give my wifi time to reconnect and then retry but how do I go about doing that? Or is there another way?

```
def get_stats(url, version):
headers = {
    "API_version": version,
    "API_token": "token"
}
try:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(f"Status code: 200")
    return json.loads(r.text)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
    # Maybe set up for a retry, or continue in a retry loop
    print("Error here in timeout")
except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
    # Tell the user their URL was bad and try a different one
    print("Redirect errors here")
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as r:
    print("Connection error")
    r = "Connection Error"
    return r
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    # catastrophic error. bail.
    print("System errors here")
    raise SystemExit(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

To set a timeout on the request, call `requests.get` like this

`r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10)`

The end goal is to get the data, so just make the call again with a possible sleep after failing

**edit:** I would say that the timeout is the sleep